# How do I know if Process.WaitForExit() expired due to main application close

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, waitforexit

I have a C# console program "A" to monitor 4 instances of another application "B".

The console program creates one thread per instance of "B", and each thread launches "B" using `Process.Start()`. Then the thread waits 3 seconds using `Process.WaitForExit(3000);`

After that time, it checks if the instance of the application "B" is working. If it is ok, then waits again. Otherwise, if it doesn't work or if it has finished, it relaunches it. When the user closes the console program, all applications are expected to end.

However, when the application "A" is closed using the console's close button, WaitForExit() is resumed in all threads and it causes the applications "B" to be relaunched.

I would like to detect if `WaitForExit()` resumed due to a failure of the monitored application "B", or because the main app "A" is exiting. In this case, the application "B" won't be relaunched, and the problem will be solved.

I tried to capture the closing event using:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);
```

The problem was that WaitForExit() was resumed before the handler routine is called.

More information:

The Main() method launches the Threads:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
       Thread t = new Thread(() => MonitorizeApp(arguments));
       t.IsBackground = true;
       t.Start();
}
```

I also tried to change the threads from background to foreground, so that main app doesn't exit, but the result is the same.

Each thread launches and monitorizes one instance of the 2nd application:

```
MonitorizeApp(string arguments)
{
    LaunchProcess(arguments);
    while(!_closing)
    {
        appProcess.WaitForExit(3000);

        if (!_closing)
        {
            if ((appProcess != null) && (!appProcess.HasExited))
                DoSomeMonitoring();
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WARNING: The application finished");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (!_closing)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Re-launch");
                    LaunchProcess(arguments);
                    inicial = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nClosing...\n");
    if(appProcess != null)
    {
        if(!appProcess.HasExited)
            appProcess.Kill();

        appProcess.Dispose();
    }
}
```

_closing is a variable set from the main thread, when the console is closed.
I did this using SetConsoleCtrlHandler:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
{
    MonitoredApp.closing = true;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    closing = true;
    Environment.Exit(-1);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `WaitForExit` will return a boolean indicating whether process has exited or timeout has elapsed. Maybe that's what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your only option is to have the main program's exit routine check to see if any of the child processes are running and, if so, terminate them.  I'm a little surprised that your 500 ms sleep followed by the `_closing` check doesn't catch this. Although, looking at your code example I don't see a `_closing` flag being set (unless `_closing` is the backing field for `MonitoredApp.closing`).

You might consider changing that `_closing` boolean to a `ManualResetEvent` that the main program sets. It's quite possible that the compiler is optimizing away the check of `_closing`. You could also mark `_closing` as `volatile`, which might change the behavior. Remember, this stuff is all happening asynchronously, so you have to worry about race conditions.

Even with that, you'll likely still run into problems and you'll have to make sure that the main application closes all existing child processes before it exits. You simply cannot guarantee in what order the operating system is going to shut things down.

You could avoid the problem by disabling the close button. See my blog entry, http://blog.mischel.com/2008/07/14/going-too-far-back/, for an example. If you delete the Close menu item, clicking the X won't close the window.

Of course, then your users will have to type the exit command in your window. And you might still have problems if the user closes the window from Task Manager or some other such application.

Comment: You're right, MonitoredApp.closing changes _closing property. I've changed it to volatile, but the result is the same. The delay of 500 ms you mentioned wasn't initially there. I put it later and it avoids re-launching the aplication, but it causes a CallbackOnCollectedDelegate exception that I don't understand very well.